# Yii import or include

Tags: include, yii, autoload

I encountered a problem about importing php files.

Why this works:

```
include( Yii::getPathOfAlias( 'ext.payu.payU').'.php' );
```

but that don't:

```
Yii::import( 'ext.payu.payU');
```

?

file payU.php:

```
include_once( dirname(__FILE__) . "/sdk/openpayu.php"); //this is a valid path
class payU{ }
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Please provide some code and any relevant `setPathOfAlias` calls (if there are such).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to do `Yii::import('ext.payu.payU', true)` because default one-parameter `Yii::import()` function call means:

> hey, just add this path to the known aliases list and do not `require()` it now

and you have to do `new payU()` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Import works the follow way:
 Open Directory and Load the Class within the php file ; condition :
the name of class are indetical to  name of file.

Instead Include , loads all classes into php file