# Alias "components.HybridAuthIdentity" is invalid

Tags: php, yii, hybridauth

I am following this tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/459/integrating-hybridauth-directly-into-yii-without-an-extension/
into my own application but I get an error and I spend many hours to find wich step that I miss. 
Here is my error.

```
Alias "components.HybridAuthIdentity" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.
```

In components directory, I create a file named HybridAuthIdentity.php

```
class HybridAuthIdentity extends CUserIdentity{`    
public $hybridAuth;
public $adapter;

public $userProfile;

public $allowedProviders = array('google', 'facebook', 'linkedin', 'yahoo', 'live',);

protected $config;

function __construct() 
{
    $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.hybridauth');
    require_once $path . '/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php';  

    $this->config = array(
        "base_url" => "touchtalent.dev/login/SocialLogin", 

       "providers" => array(

            "LinkedIn" => array(
               "enabled" => true,
                  "keys" => array ( 
                   "key" => "My key", 
                    "secret" => "my secret id",
               ),
            ),
        ),

        "debug_mode" => false, 


        "debug_file" => "",             
    );

   $this->hybridAuth = new Hybrid_Auth($this->config);
}
}
```

In my siteController, I write :

```
Yii::import('components.HybridAuthIdentity');
        $haComp = new HybridAuthIdentity;

        if(!$haComp->validateProviderName($_GET['provider']))
        {

            throw new CHttpException("500", "Invalid action. Please Try again");    
        }
        else
        { 

            $haComp->adaptor = $haComp->hibrydAuth->authenticate($_GET['provider']);
            $haComp->userProfile = $haComp->adaptor->getUserProfile();
            $haComp->login();
            $this->redirect('create');
        }
```

How I can fix it? Thanks for all resposes...

Comment: Not sure but you might be missed `ext`. Try `ext.components.HybridAuthIdentity`. Refer: [yii-import-or-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296235/yii-import-or-include)

Comment: Have you provide permission to that components directory ?

Comment: @InsaneSkull I have try but I got another error
nclude(C:\xampp\htdocs\projetc\protected\extensions\components\HybridAuthIdentity.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: How did you solve this problem?